# Creating thumbnails for all types of files in chat application

Tags: android, chat, thumbnails

How to create and show the thumbnails of the files(images,videos,documents like doc,ppt,pdf etc etc...) in chatting application, similar to whatsapp.

Comment: just see the extension of the file and based on that extension you can differentiate your thumbnails

Comment: yeah...but we can create a thumbnails for audio and video files but how can we create for files with doc,ppt pdf etc...

Comment: Looking for the solution to the same question... @NareshGunda